# Inconsistent colors

Tags: feature-request, reputation, design, profile-page

[image: pic]
Inconsistent reputation color makes my eyes hurt.
Blue jumps out too much from the green and grey.
It disturbs the peacefulness of my profile.

Comment: To which blue are you referring? The "top 8% this quarter" or the "14" box? (I'm not promising any changes, but I do want to at least understand the request.)

Comment: @Pops The 14 reputation box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that is a [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). The blue color is to stand out from the white to let the user know that he/she has earned some reputation. Just visit the tab and it will be gone. Simple. The green stands out from the grey for the same reason: to let the user know he/she has earned extra rep. Maybe red for negative rep? You should be ***proud*** that the programmers made the blue stand out. How else will you know you had a rep change for that site specifically?

So hopefully either: [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) or [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)